# Kineticjs output lags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to recreate the sinuous game.(http://www.sinuousgame.com/)
I created the red enemies,but it lags(slows down) after some time.

My code is given below:
 Javascript as follows:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfEnemies = 10;
var enemyArmada = new Array();

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    listening: true
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    listening: true
});

createEnemy();

function createEnemy() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var enemy = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: Math.random() * 1200,
            y: Math.random() * 50,
            radius: 6,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            speed: 3 + Math.random() * 5
        });
        enemyArmada.push(enemy);

    }
    setInterval(draw, 60);
}

function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++)
    {
        enemyArmada[i].setPosition({
            x: enemyArmada[i].getPosition().x + 5,
            y: enemyArmada[i].getPosition().y + 5
        });
        layer.add(enemyArmada[i]);
    }
    layer.draw();
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--<canvas id="canvasRegn" width="600" height="450" style="margin:100px;"></canvas>-->
        <div id="container" style="width: auto; height: auto; background:#000; margin:auto; float:left;"></div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rain2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfGL6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Kinetic.Animation class instead of setInterval.

They move slower since their is speed is in px/s now.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kunstmord/cP9GR/1/

All you do is start the animation (anim.start();), and update the positions:

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var e=enemyArmada[i];
        e.position({
            x: e.position().x + e.speedX * frame.timeDiff / 1000,
            y: e.position().y + e.speedY * frame.timeDiff / 1000
        });
    }
      }, layer);
anim.start();
```

Where frame timeDiff is the time difference between two consecutive frames, measured in ms.
Learning to use animations will help you in the long run, since you can time what is happening pretty exactly (frame.time, frame.timeDiff).

Comment: In the future i am aiming to use this for collision detection as per the game i am making.
Would that still be possible?

Comment: Yes, see: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection
Or you can write your own algorithm (since all you have are circles and lines, collision detection won't be too hard).
Just run it inside the `anim()` function.
I think better collision detection is on the KineticJS roadmap.

Comment: Hey thanx man,btw i made some changes on your fiddle..
I kinda need all the enemy objects to move in a 270degree angle...(in a straight path)(That means it should move towards the bottom left of the screen)
http://www.sinuousgame.com/
Like this.. 
I cant seem to find which part i should edit in here.

http://jsfiddle.net/cP9GR/2/

Comment: Try instead of setting X-speed and Y-speed separately generate a random velocity `(X_speed * 2 + Y_speed * 2)` and a random angle in the range from `(270 - alpha, 270 + alpha)` and then setting X_speed to `random_velocity * Math.cos(random_angle * Math.PI / 180)`, and Y_speed to `random_velocity * Math.sin(random_angle * Math.PI / 180)`.
That way you'll have control over the velocity and angle separately.
Also, take into account that the Y-coordinate is inverted, so you'll need to actually set `Y_speed = -random_velocity * Math.sin(random_angle * Math.PI / 180)`.

Comment: Sorry wasnt 270degree,it was 225 degreee.
Well my logic was pretty simple.
Move both x and y coordinates equally,that way it has to move diagonally.
Aint that better?
If so,can u edit that on the fiddle?

Comment: Hey george,can u drop by on my latest question? 
I coudnt seem to contact you any other way other than commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

A few glitches in your code:

- Add the layer to the stage right after the layer is created.
- In createEnemy: add each new enemy to the layer: layer.add(enemy);
- In draw: don't add the enemies there (you are adding the same enemy many times)
- In draw: don't add the layer to the stage
- setInterval with an interval of 1 is too fast for the processor to handle. The min delay should be 16 which corresponds to 60 frames per second.

Some suggestions:

- Use requestAnimationFrame (RAF) instead of setInterval because RAF efficiently coordinates draws between screen refreshes.
- You set a speed in your enemy object but you use a constant velocity of 2.  Maybe increment by the speed in your enemy object.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2WRwY/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfEnemies = 120;
var enemyArmada = new Array();

createEnemy();

function createEnemy() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++) {
        var enemy = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: Math.random() * 350,
            y: Math.random() * 50,
            radius: 6,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            speed: 3 + Math.random() * 5
        });
        enemyArmada.push(enemy);
        layer.add(enemy);
    }
    setInterval(draw,20);
}

function draw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfEnemies; i++)
    {
        enemyArmada[i].setPosition({
            x: enemyArmada[i].getPosition().x + 2,
            y: enemyArmada[i].getPosition().y + 2
        });
    }
    layer.draw();
}





    $("#myButton").click(function(){});



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="myButton">Button</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanx. I made some changes in your code as well.. I needed each enemy object to move at a random speed ,so i changed the setposition coordinates and substituted it for speed. Now the output is kinda wierd.. I want it to be smooth like in that game. http://jsfiddle.net/2WRwY/4/

Comment: Your adjusted code is not smooth because you're recalculating each enemy speed with each animation frame.  Instead calculate each enemy speed just once when the enemy is created.  Make the animation even smoother by making the max speed smaller (like 1 instead 5) Here's an updated demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2WRwY/  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval. I also recreated the the sinuous game. [play](http://fwon.cn/escape/). Here is my [open source code](https://github.com/fwon/escape)

Comment: Pretty cool man. I was just doing it to study js. And yeh requestAnimationFrame is much better. I agree.